# .NET 6 and Windows auth in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this .NET core 6 project (cannot be upgraded to 7 atm) and it is an MVC project.
I am trying to figure out how on earth to use Windows authentication within Visual Studio using Kestrel. I cannot find much information.

using IIS works but this is a bit of a painful process to debug and set things up.

What needs to be done (using startup.cs) to get it to authenticate/prompt for Windows credentials?

This is the code (main parts) for startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<MyValidator>());
    services.RegisterServices(Configuration);
    services.ConfigureAppSettings(Configuration);
    services.ConfigureSmtpClient(Configuration);
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("MyApp")
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(AppContext.BaseDirectory));
    services.AddDbContext<MyIntranetDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB")));
    services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

Launchsettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyProject.UI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "authenticationMode": "Windows",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:64991;http://localhost:64992"
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:64991",
      "sslPort": 44308
    }
  }
}
```

Typical controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller {...}
```

It just does not prompt. I get this error instead when I am needing to access resources that require authentication in the network:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions). Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, the missing piece was adding authorization as well

app.UseAuthorization();

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel) , make sure you have the codes below :

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddNegotiate();
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    });


......
  app.UseAuthorization();
```

in .Net 6 ,there're no startup.cs by default,If you keep it ,make sure you've called UseStartup method

Also,you could select as below to create a prject sample with windows authentication:

[image]